# SQL Alchemy: Appending things

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am making a simple program. I have this database

```
recipe_ingredients = db.Table('recipe_ingredients',
    db.Column('recipe_name',db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('recipe.id')),
    db.Column('ingredients', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ingredients.id'))                               
)

class Ingredients(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ingredientName = db.Column(db.String(10000), unique=True)

    
class Recipe(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    recipeName = db.Column(db.String(150))      
    numberOfServings = db.Column(db.Integer)
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer)
    unitOfMeasure = db.Column(db.String(150))
    ingredientList = db.relationship('Ingredients', secondary=recipe_ingredients, backref='used_by')
```

Now I want to be able to add ingredients to the recipe, which I will be able to with .append(), but also want to add the quantity of the ingredients and their unitofmeasure. I can put it up on my html and get the values of the quantity and unitofmeasure from there but I dont know what to do on my database side

Comment: Have a look at the [association object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object). You want to move the relation metadata to the relation table.